# Can we print only a certain page in a multi page jasper report?

Tags: pagination, jasper-reports

Is there a way to print only specific pages in jasper. I need it for pagination purpose.

ex: if I have 20 pages, i should be able to get jasper to generate one page report at a time. Can i pass the page number as a param?

Comment: i guess you are the guru of Jasper Reports...

Comment: Actually, far from it :) Just started working on it!

Comment: i was working on this from past 3 years.. but i have never come across this kind of requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question,

Yes it is possible.. atleast in case of HTML and csv reports. The code that does this is below.

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.PAGE_INDEX, new Integer(3));
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,"d://ReportResult//FinalReportResult.html");
```

Once this is set, just do a

```
exporter.exportReport();
```

In the above case, page number 4, i.e, index 3 is exported to the HTML file.